# jquery dblclcik event not giving the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Im trying to fetch a jquery object. But it always returns undefined. I have attached jsfiddle for you reference. https://jsfiddle.net/tsrdkote/

Here is the code Im using

```
$(document).dblclick(function(e) {
  console.log($(this));
  if (e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-type")) {
    if (e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-type").value != "group") {
      var type = e.target.parentNode.attributes.getNamedItem("data-type").value
      object = $(e.target);
      if (type == "text") {
        var t = document.createAttribute("contenteditable");
        t.value = "true";
        e.target.attributes.setNamedItem(t);
        e.target.focus()
      }
    }
  } else {
    var type = e.target.parentNode.attributes.getNamedItem("data-type").value;
    object = $(this).parent();
    console.log(object)
    if (type == "text") {
      var t = document.createAttribute("contenteditable");
      t.value = "true";
      e.target.attributes.setNamedItem(t);
      e.target.focus()
    }
  }
});
```

Here the current element $(this) always returns JQuery object with length 0. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object = $(this).parent();`

Should be:

`object = $(e.target).parent();`

Comment: This helped understand the problem. But using $(document.body) didn't help as it returned only a Jquery object pointing to body. I ended up referring the parent container. Maybe there is another global click event in the application. I will wait for more answers before accepting this one.